# Magento admin url redirecting to index.php/admin

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

if I enter url:

```
 https://server.com/admin
```

It ends up redirecting to:

```
 https://server.com/index.php/admin
```

and I endup with "This webpage has a redirect loop"

a) is this redirect url correct? doesnt look to be valid b) where do i correct?

note: I added this to magento.stackexchange.com but realized that is in beta, and may not get many looks

as a side note:

In the db in the core_config_data table

i changed the value of secure url and unsecure url to http://  and cleared caches and was able to at least get to admin panel.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess file in your pub folder?

Comment: its 209 lines, which section(s) do you want to look at?

Comment: this seems to be an ssl issue.  if i change the web/secure/base_url to http://  and clear cache, i am able to get to admin panel

Comment: check it  http://magentowebmaster.blogspot.in/2013/11/magento-admin-url-rewrite-set.html

Comment: Thanks @PrashantValanda  that cleans up the url for me.  The real problem is the redirect to itself that prevents the admin panel from ever loading.